# Prove that $\operatorname{adj}A^t = \operatorname{adj} A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an anti-symmetric ($A^t = -A$), squared matrix ($n \times n$, while $n$ is uneven).
Prove that ${\rm adj}\;A^t = {\rm adj}\;A$.

Comment: Nothing yet, I'm not looking for a final answer but for a path, hints. I just don't know where to start from.

Comment: Well, since $A^t=-A$, what you're asking is why ${\rm adj}\; A={\rm adj}\;(-A)$, are you not? (for $n$ odd)

Comment: Yes, but I can't find any theorem that can help me handle this question.

Comment: Have you tried doing it using the definition of the adjoint, and plugging $-a_{ij}$ instead of $a_{ij}$?

Comment: Since $n$ is odd, the cofactors $A_{i,j}$ are $n-1 \times n-1$ with $n-1$ even. So you can replace $A_{i,j}$ by $-A_{i,j}$, they have the same determinant as $(-1)^{n-1}=1$.

Comment: does ${\rm adj}\;A^t = ({\rm adj}\;A)^t$? because if not, I mistyped what should be proven.

Comment: I will, thanks. I missed the lecture about *Adjugate matrix* and I'm having a hard time with homework.

Comment: I suggest you start with samples from $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: @julien, for $2 \times 2$ matrices I got to the conclusion that ${\rm adj}\;A^t = -{\rm adj}\;-A$. The negative elements are opposite.

Comment: That's because $2$ is even. When $n$ is odd, you get $adj (A)=adj(-A)$ for every $A$, for the reason I indicated above.

Comment: That totally makes sense now

Comment: Don't bother about the transpose. You just have to prove $adj(A)=adj(-A)$. Then will simply replace $-A$ by $A^t$ in the rhs if $A$ is anti-symmetric.

Comment: I'm not sure on how to write it as a proof for any odd $n$, I just figured that for an odd $n$ when the minors get to the size of $2 \times 2$ they're always negative, $-M_{i,j}$ which brings me to understand that the elements will be equal (because the minus will set things right).

Comment: \begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^{1+j}M_{j1}\\ 
(-1)^{2+j}M_{j2}\\
\vdots \\
(-1)^{n+j}M_{jn}\\ 
\end{pmatrix} This is how my general matrix looks like, right? For $n$ odd, the last line $(-1)^{n+j}M_{jn}$ will always be negative. Where is it taking me?

Comment: Not quite right. You just need to check that $A$ and $-A$ have the same $n-1\times n-1$ minors.

Comment: @julien I would love to get feedback on my proof

Comment: Why uneven(as opposed to odd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X := (x_{ij})$ by an $n$-by-$n$ matrix. The [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), $A := (a_{ij})$, is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_matrix#Matrix_of_cofactors) of the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_matrix#Matrix_of_cofactors). The cofactor matrix is *defined* in the following way.

For each $1 \le i \le j \le n$, *define* the sub-matrix $[X]_{ij}$ to be the matrix derived from $X$ by deleting the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and the $j^{\text{th}}$ column.

Each sub-matrix will, of course, be an $(n-1)$-by-$(n-1)$ matrix. Let $K := (\kappa_{ij})$ denote the cofactor matrix. The entries are given, *by definition*, by:

$$\kappa_{ij} := (-1)^{i+j}\det [X]_{ij}$$

The adjugate matrix is give, *by definition*, by $A = K^{\top}$, meaning that $a_{ij} = \kappa_{ji}$. Hence:

$$a_{ij} = (-1)^{j+i}\det[X]_{ji}$$

We aim to show that, if $X$ is skew-symmetric, then the adjugate of $X$ is identical to the adjugate of $X^{\top}$. Let $B := (b_{ij})$ be the adjugate matrix of $X^{\top}$. *By definition*:

$$b_{ij} = (-1)^{j+i}\det\left[X^{\top}\right]_{ji}$$

We need only show that $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for all $1 \le i \le j \le n$. Since $X$ is skew-symmetric $X^{\top} = -X$. Hence $\det[X^{\top}]_{ji} = \det[-X]_{ji}$. Since $n$ is odd, $n-1$ is even and for any even dimensional square matrix we have $\det(Y) = \det(-Y)$. Recall that the sub-matrices $[-X]_{ji}$ are $(n-1)$-by-$(n-1)$ matrices and so $\det[-X]_{ji} = \det(-[-X]_{ji}) = \det[X]_{ji}$. Since $\det[-X]_{ji} = \det[X]_{ji}$, $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$.

Comment: I think it is preferable (today?) to say adjugate to avoid any confusion with the adjoint operator and its matrix, wich many call the adjoint matrix.

Comment: @julien Thanks for that. I've made the change to avoid confusion. However, I must say that, until today, I've never heard of the it being called the adjugate matrix. It is quite a while since I first learned basic linear algebra.

Comment: Same for me. When I've learned linear algebra, quite a few years ago, we would call it the adjoint. But it is important to distinguish the two notions, and I think it is fair that the inner product adjoint won the battle, as it is more useful and interesting. I think...

Comment: Must I use determinants for the proof?

Comment: @Georgey There might be a very elegant proof that I'm missing. But since the adjugate matrix is *defined* in terms of the determinants of the sub-matrices, it would be highly likely that a proof would involve looking at the determinants of the sub-matrices. The proof isn't difficult. The determinants arrive because of the definition and then everything rests on the fact that $\det(M) = \det(-M)$ for an even-by-even square matrix. (For a $k$-by-$k$ matrix we have $\det(-M) = (-1)^k\det(M).$ If $k$ is even then $(-1)^k = +1$.)

Comment: @julien According to your profile, we were born around the same time. What do undergrads get taught these days, does it depend on the age of their lecturers, and when did the shift take place?

Answer (score 1):

Anti-symmetry of $A$ gives you $\def\adj{\operatorname{adj}}\adj A^t=\adj(-A)$. And for any odd-size square (not squared) matrix $B$ one has $\adj(-B)=\adj B$, because each coefficient of $\adj(-B)$ is given by an even-size $k\times k$ determinant whose entries are all negated with respect to the entries of the corresponding coefficient of $\adj B$, which signs by multilinearity of the determinant affect the result by a factor $(-1)^k=1$ since $k$ is even. Then
$$
  \adj A^t=\adj(-A)=\adj A.
$$
While not in the question you may equally easily conclude that this is also $(\adj A)^t$, so $\adj A$ is in fact a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$A^t=-A$ therefore $|A^{t}|=|-A|$
$\Rightarrow |A| = (-1)^n \cdot |A|$

This equation can only take place for $|A| = 0$ since $n \in \mathbb{N}_{odd}$ ($x = -x$).

From a theorem we get that
$$A \cdot  {\rm adj}\;A = I |A|$$
$$\Rightarrow A \cdot  {\rm adj}\;A = 0 \space\space {\color{Red} \bigstar}$$

We will look at the transposes of both sides of the equation and get that:
$$A^t \cdot {\rm adj}\;A^t = 0$$

And we know that $A^t = -A$ thus,
$$-A \cdot {\rm adj}\;A^t = 0$$

We will now look at ${\color{Red} \bigstar}$ and both sides of the equation by $(-1)$ and get,
$$-A \cdot {\rm adj}\;A = 0$$

By looking at both equation we understand that ${\rm adj}\;A = {\rm adj}\;A^t$,

Q.E.D.

Comment: The most you've shown is that $A\cdot\mathrm{adj}(A) = A\cdot\mathrm{adj}(A^\mathrm{T})$. How can you conclude that $\mathrm{adj}(A)=\mathrm{adj}(A^\mathrm{T})$ from that?

Comment: And for $A \neq 0$ doesn't it prove the required?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can only conclude $\mathrm{adj}(A) = \mathrm{adj}(A^\mathrm{T})$ if $A$ is invertible, which is _not_ the case here. There is no proof which employs only the fact that $A\cdot \mathrm{adj}(A) = 0$ since there exists infinitely many matrices $C$ satisfying $AC = 0$.

Comment: @EuYu So this proof is useless in the matter of proving what I'm supposed to prove?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. How did you define the adjugate in the first place? As the transpose of the matrix of cofactors? I strongly suggest reading Fly by Night's answer and trying to understand it. It doesn't really use determinants but rather just the definition of the adjugate (which is of course related to determinants).

Comment: @EuYu I have read it more than twice, I just couldn't find it similar to what have been taught in lecture, therefore I tried using the theorems and ideas that were presented in class in the home assignment given following to it.

Comment: What exactly did they teach you as the definition of the adjugate matrix? The whole idea of Fly by Night's answer is that every sub-matrix obtained from a skew-symmetric matrix is also skew-symmetric. Do you understand that?

Comment: @EuYu, Yeah, they just said it's $(-1)^{i+j}$$M_{ji}$ for all $0 \leq i,j \leq n$

Comment: Right. If $(A)_{ji}$ denotes the matrix obtained by removing row $j$ and column $i$ of $A$, then notice that $$(A)_{ji} = -(A^\mathrm{T})_{ji}$$ Do you understand where that comes from?

Comment: @EuYo, To be frank, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8442/discussion-between-euyu-and-georgey)